# Add HTTP interceptors under specific routing schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, axios

Suppose I have a routing table that looks as follows:

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="login" component={Login} />
  <Route path="accounts">
    <IndexRoute component={AccountSelector} />
    <Route path=":accountContext">
      {/** lots of routes here */}
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Route>
```

What I am trying to do is attach an interceptor under a certain subset of routes. That is to say, when the user is at any route below `/accounts/:accountName`, it should attach the following interceptor:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => ({
  ...config,
  headers: {
    ...config.headers,
    common: {
      ...config.headers.common,
      'AccountContext': <router parameter called `accountContext`>
    }
  }
}));
```

However, I am having a few problems here:

- How do I bind the interceptor *once* when beneath these routes?
- How do I unbind/cleanup the interceptor once the user leaves these routes?
- How do I gain access to the router object in order to extract the url parameters?

I played with the idea of attaching this in a redux middleware, however, I don't seem to see any reference to the router without using additional libraries.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to create an `Auth` and `NoAuth` component that wraps all of the route components.

```
<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <Route path="login" component={Login} />
  <NoAuth>
    <Route ... />
  </NoAuth>
  <Auth>
    <Route ... />
    <Route ... />
    <Route ... />
  </Auth>
</Route>
```

`Auth.js`

```
const Auth = ({children}) => {
    axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => ({
      ...config,
      headers: {
        ...config.headers,
        common: {
          ...config.headers.common,
          'AccountContext': <router parameter called `accountContext`>
        }
      }
    }));
    return children;
}
```

`NoAuth.js`:

```
const NoAuth = ({children}) => {
    axios.interceptors.request.eject(myInterceptor);
    return children;
}
```

Anytime a route under `NoAuth` get's navigated to, it removes the interceptor and vice versa when navigating to a route nested under `Auth`.

Comment: I like that idea! Will try it out